# Comunicate between two devices using the same android application

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am developing a simple app to communicate between two android devices...
I am going to make this scenario for my project to make comunication between two android devices.

Is it feasible or not?
Is there any way to make this communication simple...

1.Register user with GCM after app is installed
2.store registration id with phone number.

in the application...

3.Select the Phone Number Of the Person you want to chat with.
4.Get the registration_ID(GCM unique Registration ID) corresponding to the phone number from the Server.
5.Send Request Message to that mobile using GCM.
6.The other user sends response message by finding the registration id from the server and communicates with the other mobile using GCM.

After that the communication between the two devices should happen by using the known registration id of GCM....

Thanks in advance :) :) :)

Comment: yes you can implement it.....i am not from android but i think you should visit https://www.firebase.com to implement this....or you can use any web service............

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could store the registrationId of an app together with the device's phone number (assuming it has one, i.e. not a tablet without phone connection) on your server. You should be aware that several apps which use GCM could be on one phone. Each will have a different package name and therefore different regID.

There is not necessarily a one to one relationship between phone no and regID, instead it is one to many.